# AVCaptureSession preset photo and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer size

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera

I initialize an `AVCaptureSession` and I preset it like this :

```
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
if (YES==[newCaptureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto]) {
    newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
} else {
    // Error management
}
```

Then I setup an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` :

```
self.preview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/*426*/)];
CALayer *previewLayer = preview.layer;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = previewLayer.frame;
[previewLayer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
```

**My question is:**
How can I get the exact `CGSize` needed to display all the `captureVideoPreviewLayer` layer on screen ? More precisely I need the height as `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` make the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` fits the `preview.size` ?
**I try to get AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer size that fit right.**

Very thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer respect the 3/4 ration of iPhone camera. So it's easy to have the right height with simple calculus.
As an instance if the width is **320** the adequate height is:
320*4/3=**426.6**

Answer (score 2):

Weischel's code didn't work for me. The idea worked, but the code didn't. Here's the code that did work:

```
    // Get your AVCaptureSession somehow. I'm getting mine out of self.videoCamera, which is a GPUImageVideoCamera
    // Get the appropriate AVCaptureVideoDataOutput out of the capture session. I only have one session, so it's easy.

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[[self.videoCamera captureSession] outputs] lastObject];
    NSDictionary* outputSettings = [output videoSettings];

    // AVVideoWidthKey and AVVideoHeightKey did not work. I had to use these literal keys.
    long width  = [[outputSettings objectForKey:@"Width"]  longValue]; 
    long height = [[outputSettings objectForKey:@"Height"] longValue];

    // video camera output dimensions are always for landscape mode. Transpose if your camera is in portrait mode.
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([self.videoCamera outputImageOrientation])) {
        long buf = width;
        width = height;
        height = buf;
    }

    CGSize outputSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you try to get width & height of the current video session.
You can obtain them from the outputSettings dictionary of your `AVCaptureOutput`. (Use `AVVideoWidthKey` & `AVVideoHeightKey`).

e.g.

```
NSDictionary* outputSettings = [movieFileOutput outputSettingsForConnection:videoConnection];
CGSize videoSize = NSMakeSize([[outputSettings objectForKey:AVVideoWidthKey] doubleValue], [[outputSettings objectForKey:AVVideoHeightKey] doubleValue]);
```

**Update:**
Another idea would be to grab the frame size from the image buffer of the preview session.
Implement the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`
(don't forget to set the delegate of your AVCaptureOutput)

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    if(imageBuffer != NULL)
    {
        CGSize imageSize = CVImageBufferGetDisplaySize(imageBuffer);
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSize(imageSize));
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to get AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer size. As I'm setting up only a stillImageoutput outputSettings gives me only : AVVideoCodecKey = jpeg;

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you can get the dimensions from the preview image.

Comment: After some research with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer respect the 3/4 ration of iPhone camera. So it's easy to have the right height with simple calculus. However, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gsempe for your answer. I'm on the same problem since hours :) 
And i solved it with this code, to center it in the screen in landscape mode :

```
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[PreviewLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 426.6, 320)];
[PreviewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(layerRect), CGRectGetMidX(layerRect))];
```

Note that I had to invert the CGRectGetMidY() and CGRectGetMidX() function to have a centered layer into my screen.

Thanks,

Julian